# "IN" condition at CASE WHEN on WHERE CLAUSE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause, case-when

I have an complex situation. I want to write an sql query including "case when" condition on "where clause".

Just like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE
<Column1> in
   CASE <Column2>
      WHEN 1 THEN ('OP', 'CL') 
      WHEN 0 THEN ('RE', 'ST')
END
```

Column1 must be "in", not "=". Because there is multiple value at condition for Column1.  That query returns "Incorrect syntax near ','." error.

Can you give me any suggestion? (Sorry for my bad English.)

EDIT : I think I misunderstood. If Column2 is 1, condition must like that "IN ('OP', 'CL')" else Column1 is 2, condition must like that "IN ('RE', 'ST')".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` expression for that, you can just use `OR` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE (Column2 = 1 AND Column1 IN ('OP', 'CL')) OR
    (Column2 = 0 AND Column1 IN ('RE', 'ST'))
```

Comment: +1, but fix the statement, it does not agree with the OPs statement

Comment: I think I misunderstood. If Column2 is 1, condition must like that "IN ('OP', 'CL')" else Column1 is 2, condition must like that "IN ('RE', 'ST')".

Comment: @Les - Yeah, I had column1 and column2 backwards; edited.  Downvoter, please review.

Comment: I need to write query the first column (with "in" condition) according to second column.

Comment: Now I tried and it works for me. (at first, i wrote wrong column.). Thanks for all.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from table where <Column1> in (Select case <Column2> when 1 then ('OP','CL') when
0 then  ('RE','ST'))
```

Comment: this code doesn't work. maybe it worked in a previous version of SQL Server, but I am running 2008 I think. and it didn't work.