# How to add Multiple Variables in THEN clause When using WHEN THEN in Select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, case-when

I am trying to use `IN` statement in `where` clause, I have written the following statement, and its giving me `missing right parenthesis` error message. I have google it but unable to find related solutions.

The problem is in the following statement, it works fine when i use single arguments, but it gives me error message when i use multiple arguments in the THEN clause.

I am using iReport

Kindly guide me how to use multiple arguments in `THEN`clause

```
select ...
from ..

WHERE
STATUS IN
CASE
     WHEN  $P{status} is not null THEN ($P{status}, ' ')
     WHEN  $P{status} is null THEN ('V', 'R')
END
and ..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["IN" condition at CASE WHEN on WHERE CLAUSE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424551/in-condition-at-case-when-on-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic to simple boolean comparisons:

```
WHERE ( $P{status} is not null AND STATUS IN ($P{status}, ' ') ) OR
      ( $P{status} is null AND STATUS IN ('V', 'R') )
```